# content stepping over border when doing a CSS translate

Tags: overflow, transform, css

I have a circle div with border-radius 4px thick and overflow hidden. There are two elements inside. 
When I move the elements inside it using a CSS transform they step over the border of the parent element.
After going over the border they disappear correctly, but I'd like them to disappear just *before* crossing the parent's border.

Check out the demo of the problem here:
http://codepen.io/vdel26/pen/KEBba

Thanks a lot!